# How to disable mouse wheel scrolling in Android WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-scrollview, chromebook, chromium-os

I have a `ScrollView` which can contain multiple `WebViews`. I know keeping scrollable view inside another is not the right way but this is the basic requirement for my app. I have disabled vertical scrolling (using `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled()`) in all my `WebViews`. Also disabled `focusability` in `ScrollView`'s children using `descendantFocusability=blocksDescendants.` I want only ScrollView to scroll.

There is no problem on Android device when I try scrolling as it is done on touch. But, the problem is when I run my `APK` inside `Chromebook` and try to do mouse wheel scrolling over `WebView`, `ScrollView` does not scroll. Chromebook Trackpad works fine though, it scrolls when i scroll over `WebView`. Problem is only with mouse wheel scrolling. It looks like `WebView` is consuming the scroll events and its not bubbling up to `ScrollView`.

Can someone suggest a solution to this problem?

Comment: Would using NestedScrollView solve your problem?

Comment: Same behaviour with NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround for this. Just subclass WebView and override onGenericMotionEvent method.

```
public class PreviewWebView extends WebView {

    public PreviewWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PreviewWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public PreviewWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```